Is there a table function in R that summates a referenced column?
I have a data frame similar to the example data frame below:
example = data.frame(
  freq = c(22,1,12,4,8,76,55,43,1,34),
  x=c("FALSE","FALSE","TRUE","FALSE","TRUE","TRUE","TRUE","FALSE","FALSE","TRUE"),
  y=c("FALSE","FALSE","TRUE","FALSE","FALSE","TRUE","TRUE","TRUE","TRUE","TRUE")
)

If I do the normal table() function on the last two columns, it would result in this, based on row frequencies:
> table(example$x,example$y)
       
        FALSE TRUE
  FALSE     3    2
  TRUE      1    4

What I would like, however, is a function that adds together the values from the example$freq column of their respective row, ideally resulting in something like this:

        FALSE TRUE
  FALSE    27   44 
  TRUE      8  177

Is this possible with an existing function (also ideally being able to return tables of dimensions other than [2,2])?
This is, of course wouldn't be an issue if there was a single row for each instance, e.g. 27 rows of FALSE FALSE pairs, etc., but that is not how my data is currently formatted.
If not possible with an existing function, any advice on creating the desired function?

This is just sum by group https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1660124/how-to-sum-a-variable-by-group aggregate(freq~x + y, example, sum)

Please don't delete-and-repost questions on which you have already received feedback.

The question is not the same though.  That one is for a long form data frame whereas this one is for a 2d table.

Any of these would work:
xtabs(freq ~ x + y, example)

xtabs(freq ~ ., example)

xtabs(example)

tapply(example[[1]], example[-1], sum)

library(tidyr)
example %>% uncount(freq) %>% table

with(example,
  outer(
       X = setNames(nm = unique(x)),
       Y = setNames(nm = unique(y)),
       FUN = Vectorize(\(X, Y) sum(freq[x == X & y == Y]))
  )
)

